# Sensitivities under Bachelier process

Tags: black-scholes, bachelier

The sensitivity profile like (`delta, vega, gamma` etc.) of an option contract is quite established if the valuation model follow `log-normal model` like the `Black-Scholes` pricing.

I am wondering what could be the Delta, `Gamma` profile if the valuation model follow a normal model like `Bachelier` process.

Any internet reference or research insight will be very helpful.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: First a small remark: in trading lingo we define "Delta, Gamma profile" just as "The Greeks". That makes it for everyone easier what you are after. Furthermore, yes I can derive that if you want them but why? The lower bound of an asset is zero so a normal underlying can't model it.

Comment: @wecandothis I cant agree with your statement that a normal underlying cant model it. There are many spread options particularly calendar spread on commodities (look at CME etc), which are best candidates for this modelling.

Comment: That was true; before oil prices turned negative. It's not a black swan event anymore. Furthermore; from an oil trader at one of the biggest oil firms: MR with GBM nowadays ;).